# Two way databinding in Select2 for AngularJS doesn't work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jquery-select2

I am having issues with using the Select2 plugin in AngularJS. I can load the items fine, and retrieve the selected item from my ng-model, but I have issues, that the dropdown isn't updated if I update the ng-model.

In my view the code looks like this:

```
<select ui-select2 data-placeholder="All" id="filtersSelect" ng-model="chosenFilterItem" ng-options="item.text for item in filterItems">
```

In my controller I have the following code, which retrieves the items and binds it to the list:

```
$scope.fetchFilters = function(){
        $http.get($scope.filtersUrl).then(function(result){
            $scope.filterItems = result.data;
            $scope.chosenFilterItem = result.data[3];
            if(!$scope.$$phase) {
                $scope.$apply();
            }
        });
    }
```

As you can see I just try to set the 3rd item on the dropdownlist, but no item is preselected. Is there another way around preselecting a dropdown item?

Comment: Please not that it is recommended to use the dot-notation, so keep your data in a single variable eg. `data`. For more info, see this Egghead.io video tutorial: http://goo.gl/373Ia

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Angular-ui/ui-select2](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select2#working-with-dynamic-options) github page states:

> ui-select2 is incompatible with `<select ng-options>`. For the best
>   results use `<option ng-repeat>` instead.

So, to save yourself from headache I also recommend using options with ng-repeat as in:

```
$scope.filterItems = [
  {id: 1, text: 'Item1'},
  {id: 2, text: 'Item2'},
  {id: 3, text: 'Item3'},
  {id: 4, text: 'Item4'}
];

<select ui-select2 placeholder="All" ng-model="chosenItem">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option ng-repeat="item in filterItems" value="{{item.id}}">{{item.text}}</option>
</select>
```

[DEMO PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/MKy2IU?p=preview)

Comment: My error was two-fold. I used ng-options and I set $scope.chosenFilterItem to be an item, insted of an item.

Answer (score 1):

Stewie posted the rigth way to implement Select2, but he's using "static" elements.

The difference is that angular renders select2 before having the elements called via ajax, so in this case you need to add an ui-if statement in order to add the directive only after you have data.

```
<select ui-select2 placeholder="All" ng-model="chosenFilterItem" **ui-if="filterItems.length>0"**>
 <option value=""></option>
 <option ng-repeat="item in filterItems" value="{{item.id}}">{{item.text}}</option>
</select>
```

If it doesn't work please create a jsfiddle with ajax items loading and I'll work there!

Comment: Actually, [this demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/dMSNQB?p=preview) proves that select2 will pick up deferred elements as well.

Comment: I think Dofs requires an initial preselected element inside select2 directive. It'd work but the "effect" wold be an initial empty value and after ajax finishes it appears the correct value.
Using ui-if simply hide the initial empty value.

Comment: Sure, but his question is not about hiding the element until data is loaded.